# YouTube API 3.0 Query Search

Tags: youtube-api

I had a working script written in PHP YouTube API 2.0 that would retrieve a feed of videos based on a search query.

Over the couple months it has been getting choppy and it won't consistently retrieve the amount of video views that each video has which is messing up my website.

Does anyone have or know where I can find a working Zend PHP YouTube API 3.0 example that will retrieve videos based on a specific search query?

Anything helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php

But be aware, that the V3 is still "experimental" and therefore some things might not work as expected ;)

Comment: OK, I got the new Zend_Gdata and uploaded it to my web host, but the getVideoViewCount() still won't consistently retrieve the video views for each video. It just stopped working on its own without me messing with it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can find many code samples like https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/code_samples/php

Getting started - https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/php_client_lib

Comment: OK, I got the new Zend_Gdata and uploaded it to my web host, but the getVideoViewCount() still won't consistently retrieve the video views for each video. It just stopped working on its own without me messing with it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[YouTube API Samples](https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/php/search.php) project has a great example. Make sure, you enabled Data API v3 in your [dev console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) first. Also Data API v3 is highly supported and not experimental anymore.